# Is there a PLUGIN to do CMD+click to go to the error showed in debug console (VS)

Tags: macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

When an error appears (at compile or runtime), the error shows in the debug console in VS, but I cannot clic the file or the line in the console in order to open the file directly. Imagine the 5 seconds, I would save thousands of time, (and saving eyes effort), to always open the file, CTRL+G to go to line, SHIFT+NUMBER to write the line etc...

Is there a plugin, that doing CMD+click, I would go to the line were the error appear. It would be a dream. Here is a screenshot to explain (the path of the file is knew, why not just click it and open it ?:

[image]

TKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a user voice to **Visual Studio for mac** developing team: 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/41/index.html

Comment: it is not what I ask. I want to ckick the RED line, in the terminal output to be ablea to reach quickly the line where the error appears.